# How to use python3 inside openjdk Docker base?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to Dockerize a system where I should run bash script, which calls python3 script and then jar file. But openjdk Docker base doesn't come with python, and its container doesn't seem to support ubuntu based apt-get install commands. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Suggestion: create your own docker container.  (Start by reading the generic documentation on how to do it ...).  Note that this is not really a `[java]` or `[python]` or `[python-3.x]` at all.  It is really about how to create your own docker containers.  (Or how to manually install extra stuff into an existing container ... which is probably a bad idea.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the java container based on buster instead of buster-slim. `openjdk:buster`

To test it run the following

```
docker run -it openjdk:buster /bin/bash
apt update
apt -y upgrade
apt -y install python3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quick and the answer. It worked !